# Java String Quicksort sporadically works?

Tags: java, string, quicksort

I'm working on an assignment I have seen on here, but after I have reviewed them, I still can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. My code to quicksort an array of strings seems to work - most of the time. But if I run it a number of times, it will sometimes come out with the wrong output. Any advice on where I should look to fix this would be greatly appreciated..

```
import java.util.Random;
public class QuickSortStrings {

    static String[] strings;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        strings = new String[args.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            strings[i] = args[i];
        }

        qsort(0, strings.length-1);

        System.out.print("The array, quicksorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    static void qsort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;

        // Get the pivot element
        Random r = new Random();
        int pivot = r.nextInt(high-low+1)+low;

        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {

          while (strings[i].compareTo(strings[pivot]) < 0) i++;

          while (strings[j].compareTo(strings[pivot]) > 0) j--;

          if (i <= j) {
            exchange(i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
          }
        }

        // Recursion
        if (low < j) qsort(low, j);
        if (i < high) qsort(i, high);
      }

    static void exchange(int i, int j) {
        String temp = strings[i];
        strings[i] = strings[j];
        strings[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code produce wrong output on the same set of input strings i.e. same input being provided or with different inputs... If with different input can you post with which set it is giving wrong result

Comment: Why are you using a `Random` pivot?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: You are finishing to early. what do you do after you increased i and decreased j?
Normally you should swap the elements [i] and [j] if i <= j.
Also you have to call qsort recursive

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there any problem with random pivot? I thought it is useful in some cases

Comment: The pivot describes the current position with the sort, around which decisions are made about which values need to be swapped...

Comment: @dbw - Yes. I run the program multiple times on the same input and the output changes periodically.

Comment: @MadProgrammer as I added below, sorry I should have said - I am required to use a random pivot for this assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a solution but a hint.
If I had such a non-deterministic behavior, I would :

1. Add a function returning a boolean to check if the array if sorted
2. Call it at every iteration, and only if it fails (you spotted one input data array for which it doesn't work), you print or serialise the incriminated data.
3. Now, launch the debugger with these data as input and hopefully track down the bug.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing just this - added a boolean function to check, and a while statement to call the quicksort until that returned true. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the sort is suppose to reduce the sortable range.  Basically, it's a divide and conquer algorithm.

The `pivot` finds the "mid" point of the range you've specified

The problem is, you're randomising the `pivot`, so each time you run through the sort, it's comparing some random section, probably including some section you've already sorted...

So, instead of using...

```
int pivot = r.nextInt(high-low+1)+low;
```

You should be using...

```
int pivot = low + (high - low) / 2;
```

For example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSort {

    static String[] strings;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(26);
        for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
            values.add(new String(new char[]{(char)(65 + index)}));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(values);

        strings = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
        System.out.println("Before");
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        qsort(0, strings.length - 1);

        System.out.println("The array, quicksorted: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(strings[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    static void qsort(int low, int high) {
        int i = low, j = high;

        // Get the pivot element
        int pivot = low + (high - low) / 2;
        String value = strings[pivot];

        // Divide into two lists
        while (i <= j) {

            while (strings[i].compareTo(value) < 0) {
                i++;
            }

            while (strings[j].compareTo(value) > 0) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                exchange(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        // Recursion
        if (low < j) {
            qsort(low, j);
        }
        if (i < high) {
            qsort(i, high);
        }
    }

    static void exchange(int i, int j) {
        String temp = strings[i];
        strings[i] = strings[j];
        strings[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Which produces...

```
Before
N S B A F Z X J Q K V C L R W E H Y M U G I D P T O 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
G U P Q D A W T R M E O X J S C I V Y F H L B N Z K 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
D Z C B Q O K W X F V G R S A U P T H Y I E N L M J 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
Q K H B W N J V C Y U O R P G I F D Z E L S A X M T 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
R V P G E S C A H W X I T D Z B K Q F M U Y L J N O 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
L O T E U D H N P J V I Q C X S Z W A R F K G Y B M 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
I E J F U X P K R Q L S C O Y W G A Z B V M D H N T 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
X L K T W E V J N Y G H O Q I M C P A R B F S U Z D 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
U X N T K Q S V P F W C G Y O L A B E H J R D M Z I 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 

Before
A J Z C M Y O Q F L K D P S X W N T I B H E R U V G 
The array, quicksorted: 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

nb- Don't stress of the use of `List`, I just generated some random `String`s ;)

Comment: I know. Trouble is I was specifically tasked with using a random pivot. My instructor said this would ensure the best average processing time. Since I changed from the code you shared to the random pivot, this has been happening.